# How to disable dxRibbon KeyTips?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, ribbon, delphi-xe6

## Details/Scenario:

I am using Delphi XE6 with DevExpress 13.1.4 Components and i have a dxRibbon component.

The keytips that i mean is that F, Y1, Y2, Y3... 1, 2, 3... that shows up when i press alt on the keyboard as you can see below:
[image: ribbon keytips]

## Question:

I want to **disable** the KeyTips of my Ribbon(the one that shows up when i press alt on keyboard), i have tried so many ways but i am unable to disable it, how it can be done?

## Limitations:

I cannot modify the source of dxRibbon.pas or rebuild the DevExpress Components.

Comment: Isn't that related to [`this thread`](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/CQ56188) ? [it's 7 years old though]

Comment: This solution does not fit for me, unfortunately, i cannot modify the source or rebuild the DevExpress.

Comment: See the last answer here: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S18657

Comment: Why do you hate people that use keyboards?

Comment: Haha, i do not hate myself. by the way, i need to disable it because my boss want it disabled, just that. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have stated the following requirements:

1. Your program must use the DevExpress ribbon.
2. Your program must not modify the DevExpress ribbon.

This [DevExpress support thread](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S18657) states that the keyboard shortcut tips cannot be disabled.

From which we can conclude that it is not possible to achieve your goals.

Comment: Ok, after reading many threads, i can conclude that your affirmation is correct, unfortunately. I hope that i can explain that to my boss :)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.
Use Andy's VCL VCLFixPack.

Step 2. Create a new Unit:

```
unit DxBarNix; 
interface 
implementation uses VclFixPack,   dxBar;   

var   

NixKeyHook: TXRedirCode;

procedure NixKeyTip(   AShowKeyTipWindows: Boolean); 
begin   
end;

procedure StartDxRibbonHook; 
begin   
    HookProc(@dxBar.TdxBarNavigationController.EndKeyTipsWaiting, @NixKeyTip, NixKeyHook); 
end;

procedure StopDxRibbonHook; 
begin   
     UnhookProc(@dxBar.TdxBarNavigationController.EndKeyTipsWaiting, NixKeyHook); 
end;


initialization
StartDxRibbonHook;

finalization

StopDxRibbonHook;
end.
```

After this, the KeyTips will disappear.